# systemc constructor initialization is failing

Tags: c++, systemc

```
#ifndef RAM_H
#define RAM_H
#include <systemc.h>


SC_MODULE(ram) {

 void ram_proc();

 SC_HAS_PROCESS(ram);

private:
  sc_clock clock;
 };

 #endif
```

then in the *ram.cpp* I have the following code

```
 #include "ram.h"

 ram::ram(sc_module_name name_): clock("clock",1,SC_NS) {std::cout<<"I am in clock "<<std::endl;}

  { //the error is occurring hier

SC_THREAD(ram_proc);

}

void  ram::ram_proc () {
  std::cout<<"I am in method ram_proc "<<std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting this error:

> > expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
> >      {

Comment: You have two scope blocks there.  Do you mean to have `{std::cout<<"I am in clock "<<std::endl;}` on the same line as the constructor?

Comment: yes. the clock is member of ram and  I am trying to initialize the constructor, puting some codes int the clock block

Comment: You can't just add a block into another block.  Add the line of code you want to add into the already existing block.

Comment: what do you mean by adding block into another block? the clock block is closed before the constructor clock starts.. just like hier http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: @NathanOliver I just made an update. while typing the question I mistakenly put void before the constructor. that is what I just edited

Comment: I added an answer as I need to formatting to show what I was talking about.  Hopefully that help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixing for indentation and new lines your code looks like

```
void ram::ram(sc_module_name name_): clock("clock",1,SC_NS) 
{
    std::cout<<"I am in clock "<<std::endl;
} // <- constructor ends here

{ //the error is occurring hier
    SC_THREAD(ram_proc);
}
```

As you can see you have two blocks of code.  The first block is the constructor body.  The second block is not linked to anything.  If you want the block containing `SC_THREAD(ram_proc);` to be in the the constructor then you need

```
void ram::ram(sc_module_name name_): clock("clock",1,SC_NS) 
{
    std::cout<<"I am in clock "<<std::endl;
    SC_THREAD(ram_proc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this does compile without error. The idea was to do some implementation in the clock which will be taken into account when the constructor starts. what will be the best way to do that ? do I have to pass the clock to the module just like in normal OOP

Comment: @akaAlso Not sure.  I have never used systemc.